# Oracle Rownum = 2 not returning results

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

```
USER_DTLS table
-----------------
ID  NAME    ADDRESS ROLL

1   SARAH   (Clob)  14
2   ALICE   (Clob)  13
3   ANU (Clob)  12
```

on this table

```
SELECT * FROM test.USER_DTLS
 WHERE ROWNUM =1;
```

return result

```
1   SARAH   (Clob)  14
```

but while trying

```
SELECT * FROM test.USER_DTLS
 WHERE ROWNUM =2;
```

It return no result 
can anybody please help this

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with MySQL? There is no such thing like ROWNUM in MySQL.

Comment: This is documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: @Ravi.Sorry there is no tags related to that present also it asked 5 tags that is the reason i include that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name documentation is ok but the query is not working  any idea about that.

Comment: @kordirko thanks it give me some idea

Comment: The manual *does* explain why your query is not working

Answer (score 7):

Oracle's ROWNUM starts on 1 and is only incremented when assigned to a row that passes the `WHERE` condition.

Since you're filtering on ROWNUM=2, ROWNUM=1 doesn't pass the WHERE condition, and ROWNUM is therefore never assigned to a row and incremented to 2.

[This ask Tom article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) goes into detail on this, and is very good reading if you want to use ROWNUM efficiently.