# Get value from ODCIVARCHAR2LIST at a specific index position (in a SQL query)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I'm trying to learn about ODCIVARCHAR2LISTs in Oracle 18c.

With the following list, how can I get a value at a specific index position (in a SQL query)?

For example, get the second value in the list: `b`.

```
select 
    sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') as my_list
from 
    dual
```

---

My understanding is:

It's not possible to extract list elements by index directly in SQL, like this:

```
select
    my_list(2)
from
    cte

ORA-00904: "MY_LIST": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 5
```

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581616/working-with-sdo-geometry-ordinates-as-a-table-in-a-column-subquery/72583361#72583361) with a different collection data type and only a single row of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
WITH data (list) AS (
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT (
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
           FROM   TABLE(d.list)
           WHERE  ROWNUM <= 2
           ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC
         )
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1
       ) AS value2
FROM   data d
```

or

```sql
WITH data (list) AS (
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT (
         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
         FROM   TABLE(d.list)
         OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
       ) AS value2
FROM   data d
```

or:

```sql
WITH data (list) AS (
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT value2
FROM   data d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS value2
         FROM   TABLE(d.list)
         OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
       ) v
```

or

```sql
WITH data (list) AS (
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT v.value AS value2
FROM   data d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS idx, COLUMN_VALUE AS value
         FROM   TABLE(d.list)
       ) v
WHERE  idx = 2;
```

Which all output:

> | VALUE2 |
> | --- |
> | b |

## However

If you have multiple input rows:

```sql
WITH data (list) AS (
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('d', 'e', 'f') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT sys.odcivarchar2list('g', 'h', 'i') FROM DUAL
)
...
```

then the first 3 queries all repeat the value from the first row and would output:

> | VALUE2 |
> | --- |
> | b |
> | b |
> | b |

It is only the last query that will return:

> | VALUE2 |
> | --- |
> | b |
> | e |
> | h |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7e7ab06a2b64e5561a88d3a190f53fa)*

Answer (score 1):

One option would be:

Use a custom PL/SQL function.

```
with 
function get_list_val(my_list sys.odcivarchar2list, idx pls_integer) return varchar2
is
begin
  return my_list(idx);
end;

cte as (
select 
    sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') as my_list
from 
    dual)
    
select
    get_list_val(my_list, 2)
from
    cte
```

> [5 PL/SQL Collections and Records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html)
>
> In a collection, the internal components always have the same data
> type, and are called elements. You can access each element of a
> collection variable by its unique index, with this syntax:
> `variable_name(index)`.